# git: prevent non-adders from deleting/renaming a file

Tags: bash, git

In git - how can I prevent a person from deleting/renaming/moving files he has not added? Maybe some commit hook? I prefer the check to happen locally, i.e. as soon as possible and on the sever side as well. Here is how one can check who actually added a file:

```
git log --diff-filter=A --pretty=format:"%an" <file>
```

In my case it is not about creating a bulletproof security mechanism that can't be bypassed, but rather a "reminder" for the team to obey the above mentioned rule. I don't expect my team to manipulate hooks but I'm sure that renaming/moving might happen by mistake.

Comment: Basically git itself doesn't have any kind of access control (that's usually done via ssh) or access permissions. All of that has to be done via hooks on the server side. *Theoretically* these kinds of hooks can also be run on the client-side, but that would at most be a convenience feature to detect unintended changes, but not provide any security (as they are trivial to circumvent). Specifically you can install an [update hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_update) to verify the content of the push before deciding whether to accept the push or not.

Comment: Git is not about "files" so the question doesn't make much sense. If you have rules, the way to enforce them is to tell your team what the rules are. If you need to check that the rules are being obeyed, _you_ can be the "commit hook" — or at least the merge hook. If everything has to be done through branches merged via pull requests, you simply reject a pull request that behaves in a manner you disapprove of. For example, on our team there's a rule that every property and method must be documented, but machines don't enforce it: people do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

note that git doesn't track individual files, the notion of "renaming/moving" is just guesswork based on the files' content comparison.

You can look, in `git help diff`, at the description of the [`-M`, `-C`, `--find-copies-harder` and `-l` options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Mltngt).

Also : unless the committers have to sign their commits, the "author name" is purely informational and can be set to any value.

You may still try use git to detect those renames and add a hook (as @JoachimSauer correctly commented: a central hook on the server side) to reject them, but know that these checks may be somehow bypassed (e.g: I can first create a file `config.copy` whose content is `foobar`, push it, then update it to have the same content as `config`).

Depending on what your repository holds (code ? 1 file = 1 blog post ? chapters of a book ?) you may want to think further about what you want to ignore.

---

To spot renamings, all git commands that deal with displaying information about commits (`git diff`, `git show`, `git log`) have a `--name-status` option.

Here is an example :

```
$ git diff --name-status HEAD^ HEAD
R097    a.txt   aa.txt
$ git log -1 --format=""
R097    a.txt   aa.txt
```

Depending on the hook you use, there will be slight variations on what diff you should be looking at :

- in a `pre-commit` hook (client side, run before each commit), you should be looking at *staged differences* :

```
git diff --cached --name-status
```

- in a `pre-push` hook (client side, run before each push), you probably want to look at :

```
git diff --name-status $remote_sha...$local_sha
```

(see [the sample pre-push script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/templates/hooks--pre-push.sample) provided with git for an explanation of the names)

- in a `pre-receive` hook (server side, run before accepting a push), you probably want to look at :

```
git diff --name-status $old_sha...$new_sha
```

(see [the doc section on pre-receive hooks](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/githooks#pre-receive))

Then, you can look for lines starting with an `R`, and check if the "creator" of the first filename matches the author of the latest commit.

Comment: my repository holds plain text books. I also have updated my question... so how should the hook look like?

Comment: Would you mind to post the full pre-commit hook, please? I'll figure out the rest... Thank you!

Comment: @user1876484 : check in your local `.git/hooks/` directory, you should see a `pre-commit.sample` there. You can copy that file, rename it to  `pre-commit`, and edit it to your needs.